# matplotlib scatter colorbar produces strange visual artifacts

Tags: matplotlib, scatter, colorbar

I'm attempting to add a colorbar to a 3-D scatter plot. It's actually working, except that on subsequent calls to the function, the colorbar leaves the old tick labels on the screen and writes the new labels on top of them, turning the labels into visual spaghetti. Calling cbar.ax.clear() doesn't help. Also, the graph is not displaying the X, Y, and Z labels, and there is a barely-visible bit of text peeking out from under the edge of the canvas. I'm sure I'm doing something in the wrong order, but I can't figure out what.

```
def mplPlotColorCloud(figure, canvas, vals, xlabel, ylabel, zlabel):
xvect = [val[0] for val in vals]
yvect = [val[1] for val in vals]
zvect = [val[2] for val in vals]
valvect = [val[3] for val in vals]
ax = figure.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
# discards the old graph
ax.hold(False)
ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
ax.set_zlabel(zlabel)
cax = ax.scatter(xvect, yvect, zvect, c=valvect, cmap=None)
# Make a colorbar
minval = np.min(valvect)
maxval = np.max(valvect)
if minval != maxval:
    ticks = list(np.linspace(minval, maxval, num=3))
    tickLabels = [str(np.round(x,2)) for x in ticks]    
    cbar = figure.colorbar(cax, ticks=ticks, orientation='vertical')
    cbar.ax.set_xticklabels(tickLabels)
else:
    figure.colorbar(cax, orientation='vertical')        
canvas.draw()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. calling figure.clear() before figure.add_subplot() is necessary to make sure all visual artifacts get deleted.